# how to define Sequelize model of complex object?

Tags: database, sqlite, sequelize.js

I just start to use Sequelize,

I try to define a model but my object that should insert into the db is like this:

```
{
    year: 2017,
    circle1: {
      value: 50
    },
    categories: [
      {
        Title: "cat1",
        value: 4,
        maxValue: 10
      },
      {
        Title: "cat2",
        value: 2,
        maxValue: 10
      }
]
}
```

I try this

```
const Test = db.define(
  "test",
  {
    year: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    circle1: {
      value: Sequelize.INTEGER
    }
  },
  {
    // options
  }
)
```

but it's a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the **Sequelize.JSON** type for your complex object if sqlite supports this type. This way you can save any JS-object in this field.

Please keep in mind that neither Sequelize or your DB check a structure of a saving object.